# Efficient approach to load XML and read it when needed using c#/.net 3.5

Tags: c#, xml, .net-3.5

I want to know the efficient way to store the configuration xml to be used in the program. I want to load the following config xml into memory as soon as I start the program and then use the properties where needed.
XML:

```
<ViewModelConfiguration>
  <FICallSchedule>
    <Model>
      <Details>
        <DataSource>
          <Dataset se-datafilter="callschedule" dv-datamanipulationrequired="false" dv-filtercondition="" dv-sortcolumn="" dv-gettopNrows="" />
          <XmlData></XmlData>
        </DataSource>
        <ComputePercentage isactive="true" dataorientation="horizontal">
          <column source="value1" destination="value3" datafilter="" />
          <column source="value2" destination="value4" datafilter="" />
        </ComputePercentage>
      </Details>
    </Model>
  </FICallSchedule>
</ViewModelConfiguration>
```

Currently I am reading the main tags like `<Dataset>` and load all the attributes of it in dictionary object. And then use that dictionary with key in my code. Similarly I do it for ComputePercentage and so on and so forth.

I was wondering if I can load the complete XML into some object and access each node or attribute something like: `Model.Details.Dataset.DataSource.se-datafilter` or `Model.Details.ComputePercentage` which will return a collection of columns. I am not sure if this makes any sense otherwise I would stick to dictionary objects only.

Answer (score 1):

If the configuration file has some predefined schema - it stands to reason that it does - you can use the [xsd tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to generate a class based on that schema. There is also a free [xsd2code](http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/) library that does similar thing.

But you have to define your `Model` class somehow; either by autogenerating it with the aid of these tools, or by implementing it "manually".

Comment: Any example link to get a basic idea about the solution?

Comment: You can download a video tutorial from xsd2code CodePlex website: http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/releases/18012/download/45530

Comment: Thanks Vibo for the pointer, I will look at this tutorial tonight.

Answer (score 0):

Take use of `configSection` and `configElement`, that way elements and attributes will be loaded as object, and this configuration can be stored into application config file.